# sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal().getName() null for SSO - struts2 weblogic12c saml

Tags: struts2, single-sign-on, ejb-3.0, saml, weblogic12c

I'm migrating my struts2 + ejb3 + Weblogic 12.2.1 + JAAS - Form based web application to SSO SAML based.
For Form based authentication I implemented javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule LoginModule. And it worked fine for years.

Now, for my migration, I removed Form Based j_security_check and related stuff in my login page. 
Instead of Form based user name and password, I'm using iframe where the user name and password are posted to Web based SSO application and the response I'm receiving to my action class.
SSO authentication is happening fine and I'm able to get the roles from idp aswell. 
Now since I'm using sso based authentication, request.getUserPrincipal() I'm always gettin null. 
Also in my EJB sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal().getName() Im getting

```
<anonymous>
```

Do I have to set my Principal after SSO authentication done and after I got the response from IDP.

Comment: how did you get roles? can you post the code?

Comment: The IDP is returning back the roles as a java object.